# Error bounds when incrementing float value with non-representable increments

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I am looking at a piece of code that uses a float typed variable to carry a number of seconds (runtime), which gets incremented once a second. My motivation for this question is to estimate how many iterations can be performed until the sum deviates more than one increment value from the true mathematical value it should have.

As I understand the limitations of floating point precision and from [this site](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/11/21/floating-point-precision/), I tried to calculate the precision for a sane time span of 1 year. So unless im mistaken the value after a year would be about 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 or approximately 3e+7 and thus the precision should be (2^25-2^24)/2^23 = 2 ... I assume at some time far less than a year, `assert(x+1 != x)` won't hold anymore, and thus no further increments are possible.

I realized from the comments, that the way I originally posed the question was flawed (see below). So for the sake of the question, assume the increment to be a constant, non-representable value such as 1/3. In that case, every iteration of the loop will introduce a slight quantization error which is accumulating, and my question would be how I can give a ballpark estimate to how large the error will grow over a given number of iterations.

--- Test case and results ---

I had the impression that every integer value in a floating point variable has a slight inaccuracy. Now lets say I'm counting up such variable in a loop

```
int Y = ...
float inc = 1.0f
float f = 0.0f
for(int i = 0; i < pow(2,Y); i++)
{
    f += inc;
}
int x = f;
int e = x - pow(2,Y)
```

Running my test (as C++ code under MSVC 15) yields an error of zero for `Y <= 24`, and with `Y>=25` e becomes nonzero which confirms that once the increment is above the numerical precision, this code stops working, but otherwise it behaves the same as an integer addition.

The thing I was worried about is that the error in e is more than the precision would indicate, because during the loop f goes through all those intermediate values which I assumed to be inprecise. Which is a misunderstanding, since all integers below 2^24 are perfectly representable. So my code at hand will work up to approximately 190 days.

Comment: Look at [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and, in particular, `digits` and `radix`. From those you can figure out the maximum integral value that can be represented exactly.

Comment: The only question in your post is “I was wondering, how bad is it actually that the floating point value is repeatedly increased by one?” The answer to that is it is not very bad. Is that the question you wanted answered? When posting to Stack Overflow, you should ask a specific question about be clear about it. A specific question is “When I use `double` in GCC 10.1 on macOS 12, what is the first integer that is not representable?” (it is 2^53+1) or “How can I determine the first integer that is not representable in a C++ implementation?” (it can be done with `std::<numeric_limits>`).

Comment: 2^53+1 seconds is over 285,616,414 years. But, if you use the `float` type, the first unrepresentable integer is 2^24+1, which is less than 195 days.